# How to create an async/background process within a WCF operation?

Tags: c#, wcf, logging, background-process, performance

In my WCF operations I will do the logic necessary for the operation: save a record, get a dataset, etc. and in some cases I need to log the activity as well.  However, in these cases I feel that there is no point in having the client application waiting for the WCF operation to log the activity.  I would like to fire off the logging process and then immediately return whatever necessary to the client without waiting for the logging process to complete.

I do not care to know when the logging process is complete, just fire and forget.

I also prefer to use BasicHttpBinding to maintain maximum interoperability.

Is this possible?  Would anyone care sharing coding samples or links to sites with coding examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished pretty easily using any number of threading techniques.

For a very simple example, try modifying this:

```
// Log something going on.
System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((args) =>
{
   System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("my source", "my logging message");
});
```

Inside that lambda method you can use whatever logging class you prefer, and you can include local variables to the logger if you want to log some current state.